# Having a hard time with reflection in golang

Tags: go, reflection, ethereum

I am trying to dynamically design a protocol test.

The function which I need to use is go-ethereum's `Decode`:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/message.go#L54

Then some of my code uses it:

```
   msg <- receive() //sends me a message of type p2p.Msg

   var message MyTargetType
   msg.Decode(&message) // this works correctly and this is apparently the correct way to use the function, with a pointer to the variable

   anotherMessage := output.Msg // this is an interface{}, see below
   msg.Decode(&anotherMessage) // this fails
```

I don't understand why the `Decode` method handles the two differently. A little test program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type mystruct struct {
    hello string
}

func main() {
    var first mystruct
    second := mystruct{}

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(first))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(second))
}
```

This prints the types to be the same:

```
main.mystruct
main.mystruct
```

But somehow, `Decode` above, which **uses reflection internally**, handles them differently.

What's my problem? For my protocol test, I want to define the type of the output to be expected:

```
type Output struct {
  Msg interface{}
}
```

Since the messages can be of very different type, I thought the only way is to use `interface{}`. Therefore:

```
output := Output{
    Msg: MyTargetType{}.
}
//

anotherOutput := Output{
    Msg: AnotherType{}.
}
// and so on
```

so that I then later can check that the output received is the one expected. But that `Decode` method is driving me crazy.

I have tried several things with reflection, e.g.

```
   var decodedMsg = reflect.TypeOf(output.Msg)
   msg.Decode(&decodedMsg)
```

or even

```
   var decodedMsg = reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(output.Msg)).Elem().Interface()
   fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(decodedMsg)) //this actually prints the correct type!!! 
   // But then Decode fails nonetheless with:
   // interface given to Decode must be a pointer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to Decode must be a pointer to the target type. Use this code:

```
output := Output{
    Msg: &MyTargetType{},  // note pointer
}

msg.Decode(output.Msg)
```

Use the reflect API to handle any type:

```
output := Output{
    Msg: MyTargetType{},
}

...

// Allocate new value.
v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(output.Msg))
// Decode to that value.  Note that v has pointer to new value.
msg.Decode(v.Interface()))
//  Assign new value to field.
reflect.ValueOf(&output.Msg).Elem().Set(v.Elem())
```

Comment: Yo this helped! It's slightly more convoluted as this, as if I do that, then `decodedMsg` becomes `*MyTargetType` and not `MyTargetType`, and if I use `&decodedMsg` then it fails again. But I can handle `*MyTargetType` so I'll stick to that!

Comment: @transient_loop See updated answer!  It removes the pointer at the expense of some reflect code.

Comment: yep that's exactly how I wanted it! Thanks!